# constrainlayout not showing properly

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I am developing news android app I have followed popular news app ui but it is showing very vague following picture 
[current screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdNTR.png)
[image]

following[screenshot I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjrFb.png) screenshot which I want to achieve
[image]

below my article_list.xml

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/articleImage"
>     android:layout_width="408dp"
>     android:layout_height="208dp"
>     android:layout_gravity="center"
>     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>     tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/articleAuthor"
>     android:layout_width="136dp"
>     android:layout_height="75dp"
>     android:gravity="start"
>     android:text="@string/article_author"
>     android:textSize="12sp"
>     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>     tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="219dp" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/articleTitle"
>     android:layout_width="160dp"
>     android:layout_height="78dp"
>     android:text="@string/article_title"
>     android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
>     android:textSize="28sp"
>     tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="325dp" />
>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/articleTime"
>     android:layout_width="160dp"
>     android:layout_height="78dp"
>     android:text="Article Time"
>     android:textSize="28sp"
>     tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="459dp" />
>
> <ImageButton
>     android:id="@+id/articleShare"
>     android:layout_width="139dp"
>     android:layout_height="60dp"
>     android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
>     android:background="@color/colorWhite"
>     tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="115dp"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="558dp" />
>
>
> <ImageButton
>     android:id="@+id/articleFavorite"
>     android:layout_width="139dp"
>     android:layout_height="60dp"
>     android:background="@color/colorWhite"
>     android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark"
>     tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="272dp"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="558dp" />
> ```
>
> below my adapter class

public class ArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
public static final String urlKey = "urlKey";
public static final String imageKey = "imageKey";
public ArticleAdapter.ClickListener listener;
private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
private ClipData myClip;
Context context;
private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();


public ArticleAdapter(List<Article> articles, SportNews sportNews) {
    this.articles = articles;
    this.listener = listener;

}

public ArticleAdapter(ArticleAdapter.ClickListener clickListener) {
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.article_list, null);
    return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int position) {
    Article article = articles.get(position);
    SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date d = new Date();
    try {
        d = input.parse(article.getPublishedAt());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String formatted = output.format(d);
    if (article != null) {
        customViewHolder.articleAuthor.setText(article.getAuthor());
        customViewHolder.articleTitle.setText(article.getTitle());
        customViewHolder.articleTime.setText(formatted);
        Picasso.get().load(article.getUrlToImage()).into(customViewHolder.articleImage);
    }
    customViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("urlKey", article.getUrl());

        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    });
    customViewHolder.articleShare.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String articleDescription = article.getDescription();
        String articleTitle = article.getTitle();
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, articleDescription);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, articleTitle);
        v.getContext().startActivity((Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using")));


    });

    customViewHolder.articleFavorite.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


        myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", customViewHolder.articleTitle.getText().toString());
        myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (articles == null) return 0;
    return articles.size();
}

public interface ClickListener {
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.articleAuthor)
    TextView articleAuthor;
    @BindView(R.id.articleTitle)
    TextView articleTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.articleTime)
    TextView articleTime;
    @BindView(R.id.articleShare)
    ImageButton articleShare;
    @BindView(R.id.articleFavorite)
    ImageButton articleFavorite;
    @BindView(R.id.articleImage)
    ImageView articleImage;


    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not setting the right constraints on the views.

1. The `tools` attribute only affect the preview and NOT the actual implementation. So every time you have something like this `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"`, you're only moving the view in the preview and not the actual implementation.
2. You need to set the right the constraints on the views. For example if your image needs to be on the top right of the parent view `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`
3. You need to constraint views to each other, for example if `articleTitle` needs to sit on the left of the parent and underneath `articleAuthor` then inside `articleTitle` you need to set: `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/articleAuthor"`

I highly recommend you to delete all the `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"`, the IDE will will actually tell you what constraints each view is missing.

Finally, you should have a look at the example at bottom of this page: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a lot of constraints, in addition, you have used fixed size on your views.
Because different phones got different screen size using a fixed size will make your screen not responsive to all screen sizes.

If you want to avoid this you can use [Guildelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) in order to determine your view width and height, by doing that your layout will fit all screen sizes.

---

Here is an example using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/articleImage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/articleAuthor"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="article_author"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/articleTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="article_title"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/articleImage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/articleAuthor" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/articleTime"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Article Time"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/articleFavorite"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/articleTitle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/articleShare"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/articleTime"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/articleFavorite"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/articleTime" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/articleFavorite"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/articleTime"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/articleShare"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/articleTime"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/articleTime" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It will look like this:

[image]

And if you want to change your views dimensions just move the guidelines and all the layout will fit accordingly.

---

Some tip that I can give you - don't use `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` because this attribute will only affect the preview and what you will see in the preview and on the run time will not be the same.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your screen?

Comment: I have added screenshot please check it and approve it

Comment: Adding your screenshot on my answer is not adding anything new, please edit your question with the image